# Do turning on encryption and factory reset ensure that deleted images before that reset is also unrecoverable?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

I have factory reset my device once. If I turn on encryption now and again factory reset, is it possible to recover photos deleted before the 1st reset? I want to sell my device and don't want others to recover any of my photos.

Comment: On Android devices sold in the last years encryption should be enabled by default without a possibility to disable it.

Comment: @Robert Thank you!